# Working with Panda Dataframes in Python - Date is being converted to timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have run into some errors using panda dataframes in python to read and store data in a MySQL/MariaDB database. I am trying to store a calculated date into a dataframe in the form YYYY-MM-DD. I am inputting it into a dataframe but for some reason it is being converted into a timestamp with the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" for no apparent reason.

I will not show the complete code, but only the parts concerning this date error since I have confirmed the other variables are being passed in properly.

```
 for j in range(0, final_day):
    DateW = DateP + dt.timedelta(days = j + int(First_day))
    DateWCorr=datetime.date(DateW.year,DateW.month,DateW.day)
    print(DateWCorr,'New')
    if j < length + offset:
        if DateW != ws_date[indexw[j-offset]]:
            doy = (DateW - datetime.date(today.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
            new_record = pd.DataFrame(DateWCorr,columns=['Date'])
            WeatherArray = pd.concat([WeatherArray,new_record])
    else:
        *****OMITTED FOR CLARITY SAKE**********

print("Check",WeatherArray['Date'])
WeatherArray = WeatherArray.sort_values('Date')
WeatherArray = WeatherArray.reset_index()
```

Showing the syntax of the print statements:

```
2018-05-06 New
2018-05-07 New
2018-05-08 New
2018-05-09 New
2018-05-10 New
..............
```

Printing the Date of the WeatherArray.....

```
2018-04-20 00:00:00
2018-04-21 00:00:00
2018-04-22 00:00:00
2018-04-23 00:00:00
.............(loops through all dates, omitted for clarity)
```

Why is it converting these to a different format? I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this script pulling from a db table where the field type is `datetime`?

If so, I'm guessing a datetime coming from the db is being merged with a date, and Python is silently coercing your dates into datetimes.

You could try changing your db schema to be of type `date`, or explicitly changing the loaded data into dates before putting the new record in your `WeatherArray`.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than I can post publicly due to the nature of the script. But basically, it does. But I have checked and the field type is date in the table. My hope was to explicity change the loaded data by using the DateWCorr

Comment: I ended up finding the problem, but no solution yet. "if DateW != ws_date[indexw[j-offset]]:" ws_date is a pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp.....

Comment: Found the solution. Was hidden about 100 lines away.